# NullPointerException during File IO

Tags: java, file-io

This is a simple program to read from a text file, but somehow I am getting the following error when i run it

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Program:

```
package testenglish;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class TestEnglish 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Scanner myscanner= null;
        try
        {
                myscanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {

        }

        while (myscanner.hasNextLine())
        {

        }

        myscanner.close();
    }

}
```

[image]

I don't understand why I am getting a `NullPointerException` when `myscanner` has already been initialized.

EDIT: How come I am not reading the text file? It is placed in the same folder as the source code.

Comment: You have to handle your FileNotFoundException properly. Actually you do nothing in the catch block. I guess that causes the NPE in the while loop.

Comment: Move your complete code in try block.

Comment: For decent [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872017/2587435) of reason for FileNotFoundException

Comment: The full stacktrace would have given away lots of it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This structure

```
Scanner myscanner= null;
try
{
    myscanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
}
```

is a very bad idea: essentially what you say is that you would like to load the file, but if anything goes wrong, it should *fail silently*. You catch the exception, but then don't do anything with it (except implicitly squash it by catching it).

If the code fails, `myscanner` will still be uninitialised. You'll then get a null pointer exception when you try to use it. That's what's happening to you.

You want to try either

```
try
{
    myscanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    //now do your processing inside here
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or else get rid of the `try`/`catch` structure and add `throws FileNotFoundException` to your method signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
```

As for why you're not finding the file, it's not a question of whether it's in the same directory as the source, it's whether it's in the directory from which the program is being invoked, which is not quite the same thing. The safest option would be to put the entire path in there. If you're on Windows, remember you need to use `\\` wherever you'd have a single `\`, because a single `\` has a different meaning in Java.

Comment: +1 for your awesome explanation even my mother can understand it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you get `FileNotFoundException`, you do nothing (your catch block is empty), and then proceed to accessing `myscanner`, which is not initialized (and is therefore `null`).

You should move your `while` loop inside the try block, so that you only read from `myscanner` if it was successfully initialized. You should also check that `myscanner != null` before trying to close it.

Comment: my text file and source code is in the same folder , how come it cant be found

Comment: @Computernerd If you are running this from Eclipse, it would search for the file in the default folder, which is the project's root folder.

Comment: I am running from Eclipse

Comment: @Computernerd In that case you have to move your text file to the project's root folder (or specify its relative path when trying to access it).

Answer (score 1):

`Nullpointer` Exception is happening as the file is not getting read and myScanner is `null`.
The exception comes when `hasnextLine()` is called on a `null` value. The problem seems to be with file path.

Answer (score 1):

You get a NullPointerException because the File constructor does not find the file in the classpath. Instead, what you can do is to create your scanner object from an InputStream, like this:

```
    Scanner myscanner = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = TestEnglish.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt");

        myscanner = new Scanner(is);
        if (myscanner != null) {
            while (myscanner.hasNextLine()) {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (myscanner != null)
            myscanner.close();
    }
```

Note: In this case try to also use finally to close your Scanner appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
// From Class, the path is relative to the package of the class unless
// you include a leading slash, so if you don't want to use the current
// package, include a slash like this:

InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```