# Uncompiled jar works but compiled doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So in Eclipse this code works:

```
String file_path = "accounts.accs";
File file = new File("src/puffinlump/folder_lock/"+file_path);
```

But when I compile it into a JAR I get this error:

```
Error reading file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: lock\src\puffinlump\folder_lock\accounts.accs (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Why is it not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well the working directory for the IDE is the project folder. This contains the `src` folder, however the jar does not. You need to export that resource into the jar as well and change the path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872017/2587435

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept the answer with the tick underneath the voting arrows :)

Answer (score 2):

As Obicere said, the working directory is the project directory. You try to access something in the `src` folder, which probably doesn't exist wherever you exported your JAR. You should create a folder named `folder_lock` in your project directory with `accounts.accs` in it, then get your file with:

```
File file = new File("folder_lock" + File.separator + "accounts.accs");
```

If you need it in your JAR (which it's being exported to, given that it's in the `src` folder) then retrieve an `InputStream` from it like this:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("puffinlump/folder_lock/accounts.accs");
```

If your method is static, use

```
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("puffinlump/folder_lock/accounts.accs");
```

instead, substituting your class name over `MyClass`.

If you need an URL, you can retrieve one with `getResource` instead of `getResourceAsStream`.

Note that your code must be compiled to run - Eclipse compiles it by default every time you save.