# How to write data to txt file in java?

Tags: java, path, filepath, filewriter

My class:

```
public class Test{
public static void writeSmth() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("one.txt"));
            out.write("content");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Location of txt file:

```
/ProjectName/one.txt
```

when i try to write data nothing happens with this file.
I tried:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("/ProjectName/one.txt"));
```

Got `java.io.FileNotFoundException`
tried:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("./one.txt"));
```

Still nothing happens.

What is the problem?

Comment: did you try the whole absolute path starting form C:/folder1/folder2?

Comment: @yogidilip yes,i tried,nothing happens

Comment: stupid question but are you actually invoking `writeSmth()`? It's static for whatever reason but on a related note there is no main.

Comment: @secolive I start this method in main :D

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a FileNotFoundException when writing to a file, unless the path doesn't exist or your don't have write permissions for the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.FileNotFoundException: the system cannot find the file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871955/java-io-filenotfoundexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`System.getProperty(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) to get the user's home directory. For text output I'd prefer a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). Next, you can write to your output file relative to that path. I'd also use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Somethin like,

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "one.txt");
try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file)) {
    ps.println("content");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It might not be that the system cannot find the file, but rather that the file is being created in a directory other than where the OP thinks it is.

Comment: @FredK I do not think this solution is full proof. what do you think?

Comment: @KickButtowski Note that OP never calls `close` on `out` (which is *buffered*).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch what is "user.home"?

Comment: @RuslanLomov The user's home directory or folder. It works across operating systems.

Comment: @Elliott is it default?or how to find that pass?

Comment: @RuslanLomov It varies from user to user, and OS to OS. Try `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));`

Comment: @Elliott it worked when I wrote project name instead

Comment: like this: File file = new File(System.getProperty("ProjectName"), "one.txt");

Comment: @RuslanLomov that's equivalent to `new File("one.txt")` since that property is null. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html for a list

Comment: @Elliot yes, the stream is buffered, but it will flush when the program terminates, even if the file is not closed.