# Reasons that FileReader might not be able to find the file in the directory in Java

Tags: java, filereader, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I have the following code to read from a JSON file :

```
 public static void main (String[] args){
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        System.out.println("Reading JSON file ...");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("data.json");
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
        String timestamp = (String) json.get("time");
        String traces = (String) json.get("traces");
}
```

JSON file is in the class directory. I am getting `FileNotFoundException`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please check data.json is available in JAVA_HOME directory. Otherwise give absolute path of data.json

Comment: The file isn't in the current working directory, simple as that. Your notion of 'current working directory' is probably flawed. Neither JAVA_HOME nor the project home have anything to do with it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872017/2587435) might help your understanding

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve the problem