# Gradle Build failed in Android Studio 2.1.1 : 'app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (wrong path)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I opened an application from a co-worker. If I want to run the app on my device it comes to this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\z565719\AndroidStudioProjects\DrescherBluetoothCanCom\app\src\main\java\lib\API_ADK.jar

I know that this path is not correct so it's not possible to find the file. But where can I change this path and what does this error want to say?

I found several articles with the same error, [for example this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871955/java-io-filenotfoundexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) but none of them could solve my problem.

By the way, I'm using gradle version 2.1.0 and Jdk1.8.0_91!

Comment: post your build.gradle file with dependencies. either its listed in it or added explicitly as library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your module root and click "Open module settings"

Go to dependencies tab and remove the dependency causing the error. Add it again with the correct path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now it works :) For everyone else with the same prolem: You can change these settings in File --> Project Structure... --> app --> Dependencies